# Should I solve for $a$ in this equation?

Tags: contest-math

> If $\dfrac{a^2 -1}a = 5$ then find the value of $\dfrac{a^6 - 1}{a^3}$.

Comment: Try cubing what you were given ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Contest math loves the expressions $a\pm\frac 1a$.  You should recognize your left side as one of these.  Powers of them are quite simple because terms combine.  You are looking for $a^3-\frac 1{a^3}$.  How can you get something that looks somewhat like that?

Comment: Solved! Using this expression. Thanks!

Comment: Another case if you see a polynomial where the coefficients are symmetric, like $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+bx+a$ you should divide it by $x^2,$ define $y=x+\frac 1x$ and write it as a polynomial in $y$.  You have a quadratic instead of a quartic then.